# Can I use validation parameters in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In controller action I have two parameters: params[:name] and params[:email]. I would like check them. if they not null **and haven't some wrong symbols**. Why I asking - because I am not sure can I use validation in controller and I don't know how check param for some symbols...use regular function?...Here is my try:
Controller:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
validates :email, :presence => true

def check
name = params[:name].valid?
email = params[:email].valid?
end
```

Comment: create object of whatever your model is with the params and use .validate() for validations.

Comment: so, i should send this params to model and validate them there ?

Comment: can you get me a link for checking params for some symbols. and where i should check them? in controller or in model ? thank you

Comment: consider you have user model. create a user object with the params. and then check using @user.validate() and @user.errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683100/how-can-a-controller-manually-set-validation-errors-for-a-certain-field

Comment: ok. nice link , thank you. and what about regular function ?

Comment: yes you can add private functions to controller to check.

Comment: validates_format_of  :email, :with  => email_regexp

Answer (score 0):

The validation should occur in the model. Remember the controller should only translate HTTP requests into your application actions.
When you are creating an object you are doing it at the Model layer, so the validation should be at this layer, the model.